# why n_live_tup does not matched with rows count of a table in postgresql database?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-12

I am not sure why **n_live_tup**  doesn't matched with table row count. I run analyzed command on that table but nothing changed. Why this is happen?

If live_tuple count on statistic table and row count on table does not match then what will happen?  Need expert opinion.

[image: pg_stat_user_tables]

Comment: I have seen wrong values there, but `ANALYZE` has always fixed it for me. Will `VACUUM` help?

Answer (score 0):

> why n_live_tup doesn't matched with table row count

n_live_tup is only an "estimated" value per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW).

> .. but nothing changed.

Your output shows that there were 198 n_mod_since_analyze (looks like 198 rows were deleted). So at the very least this count will be off from select count() by 198, however, I've seen cases where even when no activity is done on the table since last vacuum analyze, the n_live_tup was still not exactly same as select count() from the table.

> If live_tuple count on statistic table and row count on table does not match then what will happen?

Nothing bad will happen unless there is some application that incorrectly assumed that n_live_tup represents exact number of tuples - i.e. incorrectly treats the "stats" view as the source of truth of actual data in the table.
As far as PG database itself goes, it knows that those are only stats and not precise meta data.